# Using Perl with compiled C library?

Tags: c++, perl, apache

I would like to try and use Perl, but need to communicate with another application I wrote.  I have an interface library that I wrote in C++, and it contains the socket communications and interface protocol to set/get parameters in my application.

I would like to use Perl with Apache to serve up web pages for configuring my application.  I need to know how to get Perl to talk to my interface library.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933844/how-can-i-use-a-c-class-from-perl

Answer (score 8):

Oh Lord, if you are new to Perl. you do not want to be looking at XS (I am not new to Perl and I do not want to look at XS). See [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/~sisyphus/Inline-0.45/C/C.pod) or [Inline::CPP](http://search.cpan.org/~neilw/Inline-CPP-0.25/lib/Inline/CPP.pod) for a much gentler introduction to calling C and C++ from Perl. Drilling deeper into the XS interface should only be necessary if you want to start passing or returning complicated data structures around (and maybe not even then).

```
use Inline C => Config => LIBS => '-L/<yourlibpath> -l<yourlib>';

$x = my_library_function_that_returns_an_int_or_double($integer_arg,$string_arg);
```

Comment: I am embarrassed that I forgot about Inline::C, especially since I used to work with one of the authors. :)

Comment: The thing about Inline::C is that you really *are* writing XS, just without the worst part of the boilerplate. So in the future if you want to get rid of the runtime compilation penalty, it's not that hard!

Comment: Note that Inline::CPP is much less stable than Inline::C --- in my own projects, I found that Inline::C works always, but I never got Inline::CPP to work on my system.  This may be bad if you want to link perl with C++.

Comment: The C library is multithreaded and uses sockets with C data structures  for communicating.  Knowing no more than I do about Perl I'm  assuming that it would be a bit complicated for inlining.

Looking at your example it appears that the inline C is a call to my C library.  That of course is what I want and doesn't fit my preconception of what inline C code would be.  I'll investigate your example a little more. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to communicate with a C library from Perl. You'll want to read through [perldoc perlxs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html) and [perldoc perlxstut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html) for more about the XS interface.  If you want to do the reverse (call Perl from C), also read through [perldoc perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html) and [perldoc perlembed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html).

When you encounter specific problems, give SO another holler and someone can surely help you out. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you chose not to go the inline-C route, Perl has [built in support for sockets](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/socket.html), [A great tutorial on doing IPC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Sockets%3a-Client%2fServer-Communication), and a few [objects](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket.html) to help with sockets in general (plus, [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=perl+socket&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) will provide you many other tutorials on using perl sockets).  If you're able/willing to re-implement the sockets communication part, you may not even need the C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a module for you C++ library, if you don't want to use Inline::CPP. It can be done automatically with [h2xs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?h2xs): `h2xs --autogen-xsubs`. Install C::Scan from CPAN first.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me say that XS a relatively small set of keywords that makes wrapping C libraries for use from perl easier (see [perlxstut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html) and [perlxs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html)). In order to use it, however, you will have to learn the perl API (see [perlapi](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html)) which in turn requires a shallow knowledge of how the perl compiler works (see [perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html) and the somewhat outdated but still highly useful [perl guts illustrated](http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/GAAS/illguts-0.09.pdf)). That's a lot to learn at the same time. In short:

- XS itself => not hard
- perlapi => moderately hard
- perl inner workings => pretty hard
- all of the above at the same time => ouch

That being said, if you want to wrap a C++ library, have a look at the [ExtUtils::XSpp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ExtUtils-XSpp) module on CPAN. It comes with a very simple example. The module's not that old and still being improved, but it makes wrapping C++ a lot more convenient.

PS: If you plan to learn everything at once, learn by examples. Check out [Dean Roehrich's cookbooks](http://search.cpan.org/~dmr/). Maybe use some simple XS modules as models: [Parse::ExuberantCTags](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parse-ExuberantCTags), [Math::FFTW](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Math-FFTW-0.01/) or one of the many others on CPAN.